# How should the token be processed by Client in OAuth2 to make GUI decisions

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

I very clearly understand the OAuth2 token exchange flows and roles. What I'm not clear about is how it maps on real world scenarios. If I have a website which acts like a GUI portion (Client) that communicates to the backend rest API (Resource Provider), it requests token from Auth server to authenticate to RP. The token usually carries scopes the describe user's permissions or roles as they would be enforced by the RP. However, the GUI usually needs to make decisions based on which scopes/roles have been granted to the token. On the one side it looks like it should be introspecting the token to figure out this information to "adapt" UI to match user's permissions. On the other, tokens are not required to be readable, they might be opaque. It seems like authorization decisions are being done on both Client & RP, which would seem to indicate client is also a secondary RP? What is the intended pattern for GUI to receive roles/scopes that the user granted it access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about OAuth2.0 or OIDC or both? You've tagged `openid` so I'll assume both.

> It seems like authorization decisions are being done on both Client &
>   RP

An OAuth2.0 client is an OIDC relying party. They are the same thing.

If you are using the hybrid grant - i.e. you are using OAuth2.0 with OIDC to get an `access_token` and an `id_token` then your `id_token` will contain information your client (relying party) can use. It is a JWT token and has an information format which you can rely on. It's also transparent.

The `access_token` on the other hand may be opaque, it may not - either way it is for your client to pass on to your resource server and not to try and use itself.

The `access_token` should contain scopes related to what your client can access on the resource server (your backend rest API), whereas your `id_token` should contain claims related to who the user is, when and how he authenticated and any other identity claims about him supplied by the Identity provider / Authorisation server. These claims may allow your client to tailor the GUI as required.

Comment: I was under impression that ID token should carry just the general profile information for the user. One suggestion I heard was that the resource server expose some kind of /permissions endpoint api to allow the client app figure out how to change it's behavior without having to parse the access token not intended for it.

Comment: id_token can contain a lot more than the basic info. [See this](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-token) for more info . But yes you can also call a `userinfo` endpoint on your resource (supplying the access token) which could return the claims too.